# -[CFDictionary release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x26a13ca0

Tags: ios

I have a function where i use NSJSONSerialization. I want to do a good release / memory management because it can be 200+ objects.

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in visitsAndQuestionnaires) {
    NSInputStream *is = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:filePath];            
    [is open];
    if (is) {
        JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithStream:is options:0 error:nil];
        if (![JSON respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)]) {
            JSON = nil;
        }
        [is close];
    }
    [is release];

    if (JSON) {
        // HERE MY FUNCTION TO CREATE A LAYOUT BASED ON JSON
    }
    // WHEN FUNCTION WITH JSON IS DONE:
    if (JSON) {
        //JSON = NIL;
        [(id)JSON release];
    }
}
```

The function than does it function for 219 objects only on object 219 the application crashes with this console log:

```
 -[CFDictionary release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x26a13ca0
```

Even though im only releasing JSON when it still exists and this works (i can see it in profiler) only it looks like when it tries to release last object its already gone.

How can i fix this? So that this releas functions works?

Comment: comment on  //[is release]; then run it.

Comment: also comment on  [(id)JSON release];

Answer (score 2):

The `NSJSONSerialization` class returns an autoreleased object. Just don't release it.

Comment: I think one of the problem is *is and then use `if(JSON)`.

Comment: Im looking in the profiler and when i do a [JSON release] its saves me 65% memory..

Comment: @user983511 something is really messed up then. This is **the** problem in the code you've shown.

Comment: @user983511 The thing is that you're releasing the memory _early_, but the autorelease pool will still release it (again) when its scope is exited. If your pool is wrapped around the entire loop, it'll only release at the end of the last iteration, but since you already released the memory... *boom* You may want to create an inner autoreleasepool inside your loop.

Comment: @user983511 Something like (from memory) `for (NSDictionary *dict in visitsAndQuestionnaires) { @autoreleasepool { ...your loop code... } }`

Comment: Done this still the  -[CFDictionary release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x26a13ca0 on the last object..

Comment: @user983511 Well, you didn't understand the answer. You should ***remove, delete, avoid, get rid off, etc.*** the explicit call to `release`.

Comment: But why because this class is not ARC?

Comment: If i do a release on JSON the memory use decreases with 65% in profiler. If i delete / remove this release function its even receiving memory management.

Comment: @user983511 "But why because this class is not ARC?" - **read my answer, perhaps?** You are given an **autoreleased** object. Now google that if you've never heard of it and please stop wasting my time.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an Autoreleasepool on the function loop was the solution. My thanks go out to you guys! Learned something today..